# Shared modules cannot resolve their dependencies

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, node-modules

I'm having issues running mocha tests for a shared module. The issue is that it sits in a folder where's there's no `node_modules` in its hierarchy, so node cannot resolve the module's dependencies. Here's the structure:

```
repo
└ project_1
  └ node_modules
└ project_2
  └ node_modules
└ shared
  └ my_module.js
```

That way shared modules can be used by both projects. When running/building a project, shared modules are copied under the project, so they can find their dependencies in the project's node_modules folder.

However when running mocha, these files are not copied, so module resolution fails to find the dependencies. **I could have a single top-level `node_modules` folder for all projects, but is possible when each project has its own package.json?**

Alternatively, can you give node/mocha a path to a node_modules to look into for path resolution? There's the $NODE_PATH env variable but it feels impractical since I would have to change it with project I test.

Are there some best practices for such things?

Comment: Try setting environment variable `NODE_PATH={yourdir}/node_modules`, you can set it in your test script command